# Network load balancer - scheduled host stop

Tags: windows-server-2012, nlb

I've three servers on a NLB Windows server 2012. At the moment each of these machines has a site with a scheduled app pool refresh which I want to handle by taking that node off line while the app pool refreshes and it then warms up.

Is this possible through NLB assuming I've set a specific time for the node machine's app pool refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Full Time Skeleton

If you know what time the App Pool will refresh you could create a PowerShell script that suspends the node from the NLB Cluster and get the Script to run on  a schedule using the task scheduler.

here are the current NLB PowerShell CMDLets

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817138.aspx